# conditional frequency distribution nltk

Tags: python, plot, nltk

I'm a complete newbie and learning to use python using the natural language toolkit. 
I have been trying to analyze a text in terms of most common words in it. Specifically, I am trying to make a graph of the most frequent long words (more than 6 letters) in it. Could anyone suggest how to tweak the Cumulative Frequency Plot 
fdist.plot(cumulative=False)
so it works only with long words?

thank you!

Comment: Please post your code :)

Comment: You might want to let your rework of the question be guided by this document: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

After tokenizing your word list, eliminate the undesired words with len() in a list comprehension.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
tokens = word_tokenize(input_string)

long_words = [x for x in tokens if len(x) > 7]
```

Perform your analysis using this new list of tokens. Check out [this page](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) for a more extensive explanation.